# I'm able to scrape first fasta sequence from first page but I want to scrape fasta sequences of all entries present in 600 pages

Tags: html, r

I want to scrape all fasta sequences present in 600 pages.One page associated with the link used in code contains 20 fasta sequences and 600 pages contains 600*20=12000 and I want fasta sequences for all these 12000 FASTA present on 600 pages.

[![Below mentioned is the code which is successfully scraping first sequence from first page of 600 pages.][1]][1]

Comment: Very low rep users are prevented from posting images because they tend to produce questions like this one. Learn to post text rather than pictures. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557

Answer (score 1):

While this is not following your approach, but sidestepping the scraping issue by using an appropriate API, I would use the `rentrez` package to query to get what you want:

```
library(rentrez)
library(httr)
entrez_prot <- entrez_search(
    db = "protein",
    term = '(antimicrobial peptides[Protein Name] OR (antimicrobial[All Fields] AND peptides[All Fields])) AND ("1"[SLEN] : "50"[SLEN])',
    use_history = TRUE,
    retmax = 2e4
)
tf <- tempfile()
for (seq_start in seq(1, length(entrez_prot$ids), 500)) {
    recs <-
        entrez_fetch(
            db = "protein",
            rettype = "fasta",
            retmax = 500,
            retstart = seq_start,
            web_history = entrez_prot$web_history
        )
    cat(recs, file = tf, append = TRUE)
    cat(min((seq_start + 499), length(entrez_prot$ids)), "sequences downloaded\r")
}
Biostrings::readAAStringSet(tf)
```